# R - how to reorder rows according to variable containing row order sequence?

Tags: r, row

maybe this is very simple but I'm stuck and hoping you could help?

I have a variable

| Name |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| e |
| ... |

And a variable that indicates which rows should be read in what order, e.g.

| Row_order |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 2 |

So my desired outcome table would look like

| new_Names |
| --- |
| d |
| e |
| a |
| b |
| c |

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Row_order` vector to index the `Name` vector (pick values in order):

```r
Name <- letters[1:5]
Row_order <- c(4, 5, 1, 3, 2)
Name[Row_order]
[1] "d" "e" "a" "c" "b"
```

Comment: haha oh, now I feel a bit stupid...thank you so much!